# read data from json using groovy

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

Response:

```
[

      {
      "salesChannelName": "Global Customers",
      "customerSegmentName": "Top Global Customers",
      "productSolutionName": "Network Solutions",
      "topology": "",EDIT:
      "productFamilyName": "Wavelengths",
      "customerScenarioName": "",
      "productQuestionId": "1"
   }
]
```

**EDIT:** based on the OP comments

I am trying to check the 'salesChannelName' is returning *alphabets* or not using groovy script.

Comment: This post is unclear. Are you trying to access a specific data member in the JSON response object? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please find your question first, and edit into the beginning of your question

Comment: Actually i am new to this soap ui , and i am trying to check the 'salesChannelName' is returning alphabets or not using groovy script. can you explain me/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, follow line comments.

- Define the expected pattern for the actual data
- Extract the data
- Verify it

**Script**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonString = """[ 
      {
      "salesChannelName": "Global Customers",
      "customerSegmentName": "Top Global Customers",
      "productSolutionName": "Network Solutions",
      "topology": "",
      "productFamilyName": "Wavelengths",
      "customerScenarioName": "",
      "productQuestionId": "1"
   }
]"""

//Regular expression to check the data is characters
def pattern = "[a-z,A-Z,' ']+"

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)

//Get the sales channel name
println json[0].salesChannelName

//verify
assert json[0].salesChannelName =~ pattern
```